# How to write script for auto generating files

Tags: graphql, nestjs

i am working graphql with nestjs. when I create new module, i will create a files manually like (sample.graphql,sample.interface.ts,sample.module.ts,sample.schema.ts,sample.resolver.ts,sample.service.ts).
So How I generate these files automatically. Any script available for my problem?

Comment: Are you looking to do this every time you create a module? Are you using Windows, MacOS, Linux? What kind of shell are you working with?

Comment: I have to use Linux machine

Comment: Regular shell, bash, zsh, what command prompt do you use?

Comment: I just use vs code command prompt

Comment: Okay, VSCode uses your default command prompt unless you've changed it yourself. I'll go ahead and assume bash, but you may be using sh so things might not work as expected and may need some tweaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to create a shortcut command and place it in you `~/bin/` directory. That command would call all expected nest generation commands in the order you expect, it could be something like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]
  print "A name is necessary for using this command.";
  exit 0;
fi

# Nest has the notion of modules, resolvers, services, and interfaces
nest g module $1
nest g resolver $1
nest g service $1
nest g interface $1
# To create the graphql and schema files you'll need to run touch instead
touch src/$1/$1.schema.ts
touch src/$1/$1.graphql
```

After you save your script make sure you make it executable to you by running `sudo chmod 744 ~/bin/myscript`. You'll need a superuser password for this, by the way.

chmod allows you to give access to the script file and declare how the access should be handled. 744 means that you (7) have full permissions (read, write, execute). The first 4 means members of the same group as you have read access, the second 4 means anyone using the computer have read access. [Checkout chmod for a bit more info](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm).

After giving execute access you should be able to run `myscript` and see the output